# go-template split string by delimiter

Tags: sprig-template-functions, kubernetes-helm

I have my own helm chart and I'm trying to perform split without using the `_helpers.tpl` in one line

my `values.yaml` file content:

```
deployment:
    domain: my.domain
```

I need to split domain name in my template file: `my.domain`

I have tried to perform this by using the following syntax:

```
name regex (.*)\.{{ (split .Values.deployment.domain ".")._0 }}\.{{ (split .Values.deployment.domain ".")._1 }}
```

or

```
{{- $split := .Values.deployment.domain "." . }}
name regex (.*)\.{{ first split }}\.{{ second split }}
```

But nothing worked

I'm trying to get the following results in my template file:

```
name regex (.*)\.my\.domain
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Helm uses the sprig library to provide lots of data manipulation functions, have a look at their [docs for strings](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html). You can use the {{ split }} function to do what you want.

```
$parts := split "." .Values.deployment.domain
$parts._0
```

Comment: Thank you @alex Pliutau ,you helped me to figured it out that I had a syntax issue. Here is my final results that worked: ```{{ (split "." .Values.deployment.domain)._0 }}```

Comment: How can i get last element after split?

Comment: You can use `splitList` to create an array, then use `last` to retrieve the last element in the list. i.e. `{{ (splitList "." "http://www.foo.bar.com") | last | quote }}`

Comment: Unfortunately `splitList` is not in the Helm documentation. However, it works well because Helm uses the Sprig library under the hood: https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/

Answer (score 0):

I needed the filename of a path, so the last element. There are 2 solutions:

**Values.yaml**

```yaml
config:
  files:
  - includes/config/xxx/conf/db.yml
  - includes/config/xxx/conf/application.properties
  - includes/config/xxx/conf/custom.properties
```

**Configmap.yaml**

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
data: 
  {{- range $file := .Values.config.files }} #$file = includes/config/xxx/conf/db.yml

  #Solution 1
  {{- $splitpath := $file | split "/" }} #$splitpath = map[_0:includes _1:config _2:leasone _3:conf _4:db.yml]
  {{- $indexlast := sub (len $splitpath) 1 }} #$indexlast = %!s(int64=4)
  {{- $index := printf "_%d" $indexlast }} #$index = _4
  {{- $filename := index $splitpath $index }} #$filename = db.yml

  #Solution 2
  {{- $filename2 := splitList "/" $file | last | quote }} #$filename2 = db.yml

  {{ $filename }}: |-
    {{- $fileContent := $.Files.Get . }}
    {{- $fileContent | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```